# laravel: hasmany error when find is null

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

i have a problem.that my hasMany relationship returns error.

this is controller :

```
public function test()
{
   $a = Province::find(410)->test;
}
```

and this is my model:

```
public function test()
{
   return $this->hasMany('App\Http\Models\Places\City','province');
}
```

then if my Province::find(410) is null

the program will throw an error exception like this:

```
Whoops, looks like something went wrong.

1/1
FatalThrowableError in Province.php line 127:
Call to a member function hasManyThrough() on null
in Province.php line 127
at Province::get_area_by_province_id('410') in CommonController.php line 66
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvU1d.png)

but when find has result . the program running no problem.

so... what should i do?

i have no idea!!!

please help me!!!

thanks!!!!

Answer (score 2):

You should check if the ID you are providing to the find method is not null

OR

Consider using laravel's other method [findOrFail](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#retrieving-single-models) which will throw ModelNotFoundException if no results.

Comment: <pre>

if(Province::find($id)) //i add this code to check it 
{
       return

        Province::find($id)

        ->hasMany('App\Http\Models\Places\City','province')

        ->select('id','name','province')

        ->get()->toArray();
}
</pre>